# How to fix Bitbucket warning "You appear to have cloned an empty repository"?

Tags: bitbucket, version

I am using the Bitbucket tool in my project, so I created the clone URL and I tried to add my local code into the repository. I am using Terminal for the cloning process. while the process I am getting the error like this "**Warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.**".

I want to clone my project and I have to upload my codes into the repository. if anyone knows how to fix this, could you please help me.

Comment: And was your bitbucket repository in fact empty? If so, what's the surprise here? If not, how did you clone it?

Comment: That is new repository, so after clone then only i can add files.... i tried to clone it but it can't clone....

Comment: You added files but did you add them to the index and commit them?

Comment: For the record: In git this can also happen when you try to clone a non-empty repository but some transparent proxy gets somewhere in the middle providing content other than the requested (e.g. a redirect to an info page).

Answer (score 3):

Once you have cloned your (empty) repository, you still need to:

- add files in the local folder created by the `git clone` command.
- type

:

```
git add .
git commit -m "First batch of files"
git push -u origin master
```

Then your remote BitBucket repository won't be empty anymore.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you are cloning a freshly created repository with no commits.

As it says, it is just a warning. If it is expected that there is nothing in the repository, you can go ahead and add files and commit and push back.

to push it

```
git add --all
git commit -m 'your commit message'
git push origin master
```

If it is not supposed to be empty, contact the person/admin who gave you the link.